# How to filtrate a long string (dynamic) with regex?

Tags: java, regex

I have stored the response from a web-application in a string. The string contains several URL:s, and it is dynamic. Could be anything from 10-1000 URL:s.

I work with performance engineering, but this time I have to code a plugin in java, and I am far from an expert in programming.

The problem I have is that in my response-string, I have a lot of gibberish that I don't need, and I don't know how to filtrate it. In my print/request I only want to send the URLS.

I've come this far:

```
responseData = "http://xxxx-f.akamaihd.net/i/world/open/20150426/1370235-005A/EPISOD-65354-005A-016f1729028090bf_,892,144,252,360,540,1584,2700,.mp4.csmil/segment1_4_av.ts?null=" +
                "#EXTINF:10.000, " + 
                "http://xxxxx-f.akamaihd.net/i/world/open/20150426/1370235-005A/EPISOD-65365-005A-016f1729028090bf_,892,144,252,360,540,1584,2700,.mp4.csmil/segment2_4_av.ts?null=" + 
                "#EXTINF:fgsgsmoregiberish, " + 
                "http://xxxx-f.akamaihd.net/i/world/open/20150426/1370235-005A/EPISOD-6353-005A-016f1729028090bf_,892,144,252,360,540,1584,2700,.mp4.csmil/segment2_4_av.ts?null=";


            pattern = "^(http://.*\\.ts)";



             pr = Pattern.compile(pattern); 

             math = pr.matcher(responseData);


            if (math.find()) {
                System.out.println(math.group());


// in this print, I get everything from the response. I only want the URLS (dynamic. could be different names, but they all start with http and end with .ts). 
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("No Math");
            }
```

Comment: Could you give an example of what represents the `UR` part of your string?

Comment: @bot It's in my code. "http://xxxx-f.akamaihd.net/i/world/open/20150426/1370235-005A/EPISOD-6353-005A-016f1729028090bf_,892,144,252,360,540,1584,2700,.mp4.csmil/segment2_4_av.ts?null="

Comment: Why do you use `^`? It forces a match at the beginning of a string. Try `pattern = "http://.*\\.ts";`. No need in brackets.

Comment: @stribizhev Still getting the "#EXTINF:10.000" which I want to filtrate.

Comment: @stribizhev `"http://.*\\.ts"` will catch `http://abc.123.ts some other chars http://abc.456.ts` as a single match

Comment: @SashaSalauyou: So, you need lazy matching: `"http://.*?\\.ts\\b"` + a word boundary.

Comment: @stribizhev yes exactly

Answer (score 2):

Depending of how looks your URLs, you can use this naive pattern that works for your examples and stops before the `?` (written in java style):

```
\\bhttps?://[^?\\s]+
```

to ensure there is `.ts` at the end, you can change it to:

```
\\bhttps?://[^?\\s]+\\.ts
```

or

```
\\bhttps?://[^?\\s]+\\.ts(?=[\\s?]|\\z)
```

to check that the end of the path is reached.

Note that these patterns don't deal with URLs that contain spaces between double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following regex pattern:

`(((http|ftp|https):\/{2})+(([0-9a-z_-]+\.)+([a-z]{2,4})(:[0-9]+)?((\/([~0-9a-zA-Z\#\+\%@\.\/_-]+))?(\?[0-9a-zA-Z\+\%@\/&\[\];=_-]+)?)?))\b`

Explanation:

- contains http or https or ftp with // : `((http|ftp|https):\/{2})`
- now add '+' sign to add next part in the same string
- URL name with one . : ([0-9a-z_-]+.)
- domain name : ([a-z]{2,4})
- any digit occurs no or one time (here ? denote non or one time) : (:[0-9]+)?
- rest url occurs non or one time : '(/([~0-9a-zA-Z#+\%@./_-]+))?(\?[0-9a-zA-Z+\%@/&[];=_-]+)?)'

Comment: isn't `(www\\.)` subset of `([a-zA-Z0-9]+\\.)` ?

Comment: by the way, what if first level domain is `info` or `academy`--many of top domains exceeding 3 latin characters exist nowadays.

Comment: yes (www\\.) is subset of ([a-zA-Z0-9]+\\.) but its constant as well so better use the constant value instead of giving full regex. its just simple optimization

Comment: I agree thats why i explained why i added {2,3} we can change as per the requirement.

Comment: what about `/`, `=` and `&` in the path? Another charsets? Capital letters? Your regex catches only sequence of lowercase latin characters after dot. BTW, the dot also must be escaped.

Comment: I have edited the ans as per your doubts previously it was just ans example to use. Now we can directly copy paste and use it..

Answer (score 0):

Just make you regex lazy with `.*?` instead of greedy `.*`, i.e.:

```
pr = Pattern.compile("(https?.*?\\.ts)");
```

---

Regex demo:

https://regex101.com/r/nQ5pA7/1

---

Regex Explanantion:

```
(https?.*?\.ts)

Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(https?.*?\.ts)»
   Match the character string “http” literally (case sensitive) «http»
   Match the character “s” literally (case sensitive) «s?»
      Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «?»
   Match any single character that is NOT a line break character (line feed, carriage return, next line, line separator, paragraph separator) «.*?»
      Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
   Match the character “.” literally «\.»
   Match the character string “ts” literally (case sensitive) «ts»
```